# Cannot access variable within expect_background

Tags: tcl, expect

I have this code that starts a process, `expect`s some startup output, and then logs the rest to a file:

```
proc foo { } {
    set log_fp [open "somefile" a]

    exec cp $prog "$prog.elf"

    spawn someprog
    set someprog_spawn_id $spawn_id

    # do some things here that that wait for output from someprog
    expect {
        -i $someprog_spawn_id
        -re "Some output indicating successful startup"
    }

    # send the process into the background
    expect_background {
        -i $someprog_spawn_id
        full_buffer { }
        eof {
            wait -i $someprog_spawn_id
            close $log_fp 
        }
        -re {^.*\n} {
            puts $log_fp $expect_out(buffer)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this errors with the message:

```
can't read "log_fp": no such variable
```

How can I access this variable within this scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expect_background` callback scripts are evaluated in the global scope (because the procedure may well have finished at the point when they fire) so you have to put the variable in that scope as well…

```
proc foo { } {
    global log_fp
    set log_fp [open "somefile" a]
    # ...
```

Alternatively, with 8.5 you can do some tricks with using `apply` to make a binding

```
expect_background "
    -i \$someprog_spawn_id
    full_buffer { }
    [list eof [list apply {log_fp {
        wait -i $someprog_spawn_id
        close $log_fp 
    }} $log_fp]]
    [list -re {^.*\n} [list apply {log_fp {
        puts $log_fp $expect_out(buffer)
    }} $log_fp]]
"
```

*Really* ugly though. Using a global variable is a lot easier.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be that ugly, since `expect` can take more than one arg. I won't attempt to rewrite that in a comment though.